# How to specify row id using data option in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid and tableToGrid plugin but found that it's relatively slow with a large table. So I would like to rewrite it using the jqgrid's `data` option instead of using the original `addRowData` method. However, I cannot find any reference about specifying the row id using the `data` option. The grid just generate the id starting from 1 but I would like to specific the id in my row of data.

Do I need to use `localReader` together to make it work? A sample piece of code will be appreciated.

Here's my grid declaration. (edited from the original tabletogrid)

```
jQuery(this).jqGrid(jQuery.extend({
        datatype: "local",
        data:data,          
        width: w,
        colNames: colNames,
        colModel: colModel,
        multiselect: selectMultiple
        //inputName: inputName,
        //inputValueCol: imputName != null ? "__selection__" : null
    }, options || {}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured it out using localReader. Here's the modified tableToGrid with better performance.

```
function tableToGrid(selector, options) {
jQuery(selector).each(function() {
    if(this.grid) {return;} //Adedd from Tony Tomov
    // This is a small "hack" to make the width of the jqGrid 100%
    jQuery(this).width("99%");
    var w = jQuery(this).width();

    // Text whether we have single or multi select
    var inputCheckbox = jQuery('input[type=checkbox]:first', jQuery(this));
    var inputRadio = jQuery('input[type=radio]:first', jQuery(this));
    var selectMultiple = inputCheckbox.length > 0;
    var selectSingle = !selectMultiple && inputRadio.length > 0;
    var selectable = selectMultiple || selectSingle;
    //var inputName = inputCheckbox.attr("name") || inputRadio.attr("name");

    // Build up the columnModel and the data
    var colModel = [];
    var colNames = [];
    jQuery('th', jQuery(this)).each(function() {
        if (colModel.length === 0 && selectable) {
            colModel.push({
                name: '__selection__',
                index: '__selection__',
                width: 0,
                hidden: true
            });
            colNames.push('__selection__');
        } else {
            colModel.push({
                name: jQuery(this).attr("id") || jQuery.trim(jQuery.jgrid.stripHtml(jQuery(this).html())).split(' ').join('_'),
                index: jQuery(this).attr("id") || jQuery.trim(jQuery.jgrid.stripHtml(jQuery(this).html())).split(' ').join('_'),
                width: jQuery(this).width() || 150
            });
            colNames.push(jQuery(this).html());
        }
    });
    var data = [];
    var rowIds = [];
    var rowChecked = [];
    jQuery('tbody > tr', jQuery(this)).each(function() {
        var row = [];
        var rowobj = {};
        var rowPos = 0;
        jQuery('td', jQuery(this)).each(function() {
            if (rowPos === 0 && selectable) {
                var input = jQuery('input', jQuery(this));
                var rowId = input.attr("value");
                rowIds.push(rowId || data.length);
                rowobj["id"] = rowId || data.length;
                if (input.attr("checked")) {
                    rowChecked.push(rowId);
                }
                //row[colModel[rowPos].name] = input.attr("value");
                row.push( input.attr("value"));
            } else {
                //row[colModel[rowPos].name] = jQuery(this).html();
                row.push(jQuery(this).html());
            }
            rowPos++;
        });
        if(rowPos >0) { rowobj["cell"] = row; data.push(rowobj); }
    });

    // Clear the original HTML table
    jQuery(this).empty();

    // Mark it as jqGrid
    jQuery(this).addClass("scroll");

    jQuery(this).jqGrid(jQuery.extend({
        datatype: "local",
        data:data,
        localReader: {
            repeatitems: true,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id"
        },
        gridview: true,
        width: w,
        colNames: colNames,
        colModel: colModel,
        multiselect: selectMultiple
        //inputName: inputName,
        //inputValueCol: imputName != null ? "__selection__" : null
    }, options || {}));


    // Set the selection
    for (a = 0; a < rowChecked.length; a++) {
        jQuery(this).jqGrid("setSelection",rowChecked[a]);
    }
});
};
```

Comment: Small remarks: `id: "id"` of `localReader` is the default value (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data)) so you don't need to define it. To fill `data` you can just include `id` property in the elements of the `data` array. Next: always where you use `jQuery(this)` as the jQuery context (like in `jQuery('td', jQuery(this))`) you should use just `this` (like `jQuery('td', this)`). The usage of `jQuery(this)` many time with the same value `this` can be optimized introducing additional variable (like 'var $this = jQuery(this);')

Comment: You don't need use `cell` inside of `data`. The default value in `localReader` is `repeatitems: false`. So you can just place in `data` array elements having as properties the `'name'` from the `colModel` and additional property `id`. In general you are write that the usage of `addRowData` in the `tableToGrid` plugin is ineffective. You should post the suggestion to [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393).

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for the tips. Actually most of the code is from the original tabletoGrid() bundled in jqgrid, I just try to modify the bit on replacing addRowData() with the data option. I tried to keep most of the original logic in the function and so I used the id parameter. I didn't want to specify the cell but jqgrid didnt seem to recognize the {key:value} array in the data if I specified the id. So I need to change the row data to be stored in the cell array instead.

Comment: You are right. The most things about which I wrote are from the original code of `tabletoGrid`. The code of jqGrid is not perfect, but we both use it. About the usage of named properties: I permanently use it and it works. Look at [the example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGrid.htm) or use `getGridParam` with `data` parameter to get the `data` from the grid filled with `loadonce:true`. I want one more time repeat my suggestion to post to trirand your changing to use `data` parameter instead of `addRowData`. It can be helpful for other.